# FileServlet broken video in download

Tags: java, jsf

Well, i'm trying to use a FileServlet to download video from my webserver (Apache Tomcat), but this video BROKEN. I know that video is OK because if i download with FileZilla everything works fine.

See my class:

```
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Constants
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.

    // Properties
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private String filePath;

    // Actions
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static abstract class InnerFacesContext extends FacesContext {

    protected static void setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(
            FacesContext facesContext) {
        FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
    }

    private InnerFacesContext() {
    }
    }

    public void init() throws ServletException {

    // In a Windows environment with the Applicationserver running on the
    // c: volume, the above path is exactly the same as "c:\files".
    // In UNIX, it is just straightforward "/files".
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    this.filePath = getFacesContext(request, response).getExternalContext()
            .getInitParameter("tmpDirectory");

    // Get requested file by path info.
    String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();

    // Check if file is actually supplied to the request URI.
    if (requestedFile == null) {
        // Do your thing if the file is not supplied to the request URI.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or
        // just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file
    // object.
    File file = new File(filePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));

    // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
    if (!file.exists()) {
        // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
        // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or
        // just ignore it.
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
        return;
    }

    // Get content type by filename.
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

    // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
    // For all content types, see:
    // http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
    // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
    if (contentType == null) {
        contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    // Init servlet response.
    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

    // Prepare streams.
    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        // Open streams.
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        // Write file contents to response.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        // Gently close streams.
        close(output);
        close(input);
    }
    }

    // Helpers (can be refactored to public utility class)
    // ----------------------------------------

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) {
        try {
        resource.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail
        // it.
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

    protected FacesContext getFacesContext(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (facesContext == null) {
        FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder
            .getFactory("javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory");
        LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder
            .getFactory("javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory");
        javax.faces.lifecycle.Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory
            .getLifecycle("DEFAULT");
        facesContext = contextFactory.getFacesContext(request.getSession()
            .getServletContext(), request, response, lifecycle);
        InnerFacesContext.setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(facesContext);
        javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot view = facesContext
            .getApplication().getViewHandler()
            .createView(facesContext, "");
        facesContext.setViewRoot(view);
    }
    return facesContext;
    }

}
```

PS: This class if from BalusC blog.

Comment: Have you tried flushing your buffer by calling the `flush` method?

Comment: How is the video broken - is the file created?  Is it empty?  Is it there, but smaller than the expected video?  Also, have you considered using Apache Commons IOUtils for copying the streams?  It will make you life much easier!

Comment: @CKing, How can i do It ?

Comment: @hugh, my file is created with same size but i cant view in VLC player.